# How to import npm modules with typescript / gulp / browserify

Tags: typescript, npm, gulp, browserify

I'm struggling with some very basic things like importing packages I installed with NPM. I honestly tried googling it a lot, and tried out different tutorials, but I can't get it to work. Here is my current setup, trying with gulp, I guess I'm missing something quite basic. I want to be able to use it directly in browser, so I followed a tutorial using browserify (but also tried other tutorials without luck)

I installed (e.g. webmidi via npm) and my folder structure looks like this:

```
proj
+--node_modules
    +--module1
    +--module2
    +--webmidi
+--dist
+--src
    +--main.ts
    +--index.html
```

My Gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webmidi = require('webmidi');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require('tsify');
var paths = {
    pages: ['src/*.html']
};

gulp.task('copy-html', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.pages)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('copy-html'), function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['src/main.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
    .plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}));
```

main.ts:

```
import * as webmidi from "webmidi";

console.log(WebMidi);
package.json:

{
  "name": "ts4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.5.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-require-modules": "^1.1.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "tsify": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.2",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webmidi": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

The error I get when i do

```
>gulp
[23:36:55] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Projekte\code\ts4\gulpfile.js
[23:36:55] Starting 'default'...
[23:36:55] Starting 'copy-html'...
[23:36:55] Finished 'copy-html' after 39 ms
[23:36:55] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[23:36:57] '<anonymous>' errored after 2.21 s
[23:36:57] Error: TypeScript error: c:/users/username/documents/projekte/code/ts4/src/main.ts(4,13): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebMidi'.
    at formatError (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\format-error.js:21:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\log\events.js:33:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Object.error (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\code\ts4\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\createExtensions.js:61:10)
    at handler (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\code\ts4\node_modules\now-and-later\lib\mapSeries.js:47:14)
    at f (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\code\ts4\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at f (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\code\ts4\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\code\ts4\node_modules\async-done\index.js:24:15)
    at done (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\code\ts4\node_modules\async-done\index.js:40:12)
[23:36:57] 'default' errored after 2.26 s
```

According to https://github.com/djipco/webmidi/issues/82 this is the right way to import WebMidi, and it should work - i guess I'm doing something wrong, can anyone help me?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first foray into bundlers (as it appears it is), I suggest trying [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

It's dead simple to use, requiring basically no setup.

If you have an `index.html` file that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.sass">
</head>
<body></body>
<script src="./index.ts"></script>
</html>
```

Notice that I used a typescript and a sass file *directly* in the html. This is why Parcel is cool. After installing parcel (usually globally, per their instructions), you can call `parcel index.html` and it will automagically install all your dependencies and serve it up on an auto-reloading page with source maps.

It's pretty neat. For other npm packages, you just `npm i [package]` in the project directory, use `import { [whatever] } from '[package]'` in your typescript file, and you're good to go.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't work for me either, It "compiles" without error, but when I try to access the stuff from webmidi I get an error saying that he can't find WebMidi (which is supposed to be a singleton defined in webmidi). But it looks like a problem with webmidi and typescript, so I'm going to ask in the webmidi issue-tracker.

Comment: might need to `npm i @types/webmidi`